# Historize sql data in Parent-Child tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, foreign-key-relationship

1 Map has N Images. When a the user updates the Map data I do not make an update because then I lose the old data. Thus I do an Insert into the Map table with the same auto incremented Id but a new datetime stamp. This way I want to historize all changes on a Map in the user interface.

Table Map: PK is Id + CreatedAt

```
 [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, 
 [CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,   
 ...
```

Table Images: PK is Id, FK is MapId + CreatedAt

```
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Image] [varbinary](max) NOT NULL,
[VisibleIndex] [int] NOT NULL,
[CreatedAt] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[MapId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

If I have a PK with 2 fields my FK must also have 2 fields.

But this does not work in my case because the CreatedAt date from table Images cant be the createdAt date from the table Map.

How would you do the historical "update" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Separate "constant" and "evolvable" aspects of the map into two tables:

[image]

This assumes you only want to version the map fields but not images.

---

If you also want to version images, you could do it like this:

[image]

When creating a new Map version:

- For images that didn't change: just copy the links but don't create new image versions.
- For images that did change: create new image versions **and** links.

This way, you don't have to do expensive copying of the image content just because the map has changed. You only create a new image version when the image itself has changed.

*NOTE: This model is a little too general. It allows same images to be shared between multiple maps (not just multiple versions of the same map). Let me know if you'd like to restrict that.*

---

To make images "private" to the map, you can do something like this:

[image]

Note how we **don't** introduce any surrogate keys. Instead, we let identifying relationships produce "natural" keys, which then get merged at the bottom of the diamond-shaped dependencies: `ImageLink.MapId` has foreign keys toward both "edges" of the "diamond"

Comment: Restriction: an image should belong to one map only.1 map has N images. Not N maps have M images.

Comment: @Pascal Do images need to be versioned?

Comment: yes would be good. I know from a former company where I worked they did historize every table to track everything. I still know their Foreign-Key-Tables had no FK´s at all and every data record had a ValidFrom and ValidUntil field. JFYI in general. They did it differently to your suggestion.

Comment: sorry, but images does not need historization. For this feature is actually no use case;-) Being able to check what was changed on the map by whom (CreatedBy) is enough for me. No overengineering ;-)

Comment: @Pascal Then the first model should do fine ;)

Comment: I thought about this again. Why do I need for this case at all 3 tables? Why not make Map (Id + CreatedAt) as PK and the MapId (FK) from Images table has the images not historized but every datarecord in the Map table with Id 10 has the same image with MapdId (FK) 10. That would mean when I have 5 historized map records with Id 10 they  all have an image with mapId (FK) 10.

Comment: 2.)The ImageLink table which offers historization for images TOO. It has also 3 tables. Not really much more overhead then without images historization. When I historize a MapVersion record I just insert in the MapVersion table. When I historize a ImageVersion I just insert in the ImageVersion table AND insert in the ImageLink (MapImage) table all 4 values. I guess due to not much overhead I go with the histrorization of Map + Image table which I just understood :)

Comment: 3.) and yes as you wrote on creating a new Map data record I will only make an entry for the image record in the ImageLink table when the image did not change else I create also new record in the ImageVersion table.

Comment: maybe you still have a hint for me as I use Identity Columns (auto generated ids) for MapId and ImageId. When my model has Map.MapId = -1 in my Data Access Layer.StoreMethod() I use the auto generated id for MapId + CreatedAt datetime. Next time I change the Map record the Map.MapId is not -1 anymore its 1 or 5 or 11. Thus I have to do an insert with Identity column turned off to do an insert with the same id but different createdat datetime. Do you think that approach is good?

Comment: @Pascal Correct, you shouldn't use auto-increment in `MapVersion`.

Comment: agree... just like I did before. Using auto increment with identity_insert on/off at least in my unit-tests... Thanks. Forget about the -1 stuff, got a better solution now ;-)

Comment: Branko, are you still alive and kicking? How would you restrict the same image only to be shared between multiple version of the same map? I would be grateful for this side answer ;-)

Comment: Thanks Branko that looks hell of interesting and complicated the same time ;-)

Comment: With your second image a4Lwl.png the 3 tables and N:M relation I have a problem now. How can an image change? Its not text. Either an image is added or its deleted. How can I then follow your recommendation:"When creating a new Map version:" The 2 points... The first seems ok I just do new entries in the ImageLink table referencing the old image. Now I have 2 entries in the MapVersion and ImageLink table pointing to 1 ImageVersion??? That seems wrong, because when I delete an image in the ImageVersion its gone for the 2 references in the ImageLink table. You understand me?

Comment: @Pascal An image changes by adding a new row into `ImageVersion` (and probably `ImageLink` as well). I'm not sure I understand what exactly is the problem...

Comment: Ok but this would that the ImageVersion table could contain 2 imageId`s with 2 different dates but the same byte data (real image). Do you agree? If yes I have to make a copy of ImageId1/2010-10-10 and insert it into ImageId1/2011-10-10 when the MapVersion is changed.

Comment: @Pascal Yes, in theory the `ImageVersion` could contain two rows with the same image bytes. There may be ways for the DBMS to prevent this (e.g. calculate a [SHA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Hash_Algorithm) from the image bytes, and make that hash a key), but this is a separate problem, orthogonal to the versioning. I don't see why would you need to create a new `ImageVersion` when creating a new `MapVersion` (unless the images itself has changed) - you just need to copy the appropriate rows within `ImageLink`, as explained in the answer.

Comment: YES but I would copy only within ImageLink and the user would delete the image in the ImageVersion. How should the raw image data be deleted? If the raw image data is deleted indeed the 2nd reference in the Imagelink table will not anymore point to the former existing raw image data.

Comment: @Pascal The cascading referential integrity (ON DELETE CASCADE) will delete both links. If you don't use cascading delete, the DBMS will simply forbid you from doing it (you'll get a foreign key violation). On the other hand, if you want to logically "delete" the image **just** from the latest map version, simply omit the corresponding link (the `ImageVersion` itself and the links to previous map versions remain in place).

Comment: yes true the RI (ODCascade) will delete both. I just thought it should only delete the image for a certain MapVersion (id and date) else this is not truly historized. what do you think?

Comment: @Pascal There is no such thing as _"image for a certain MapVersion"_. Only links (not image versions) are specific to a map version.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If your primary key on the `Map` table is the single column `Id`, then your foreign key in the `Images` table is really just the column `MapId`, which references the `Id` column on the parent table.</strike>

If the primary key on the `Map` table is the single column `Id`, then you won't be able to insert another row with the same value as `Id`.

Inserting rows with specified value for an IDENTITY column can be done, but you have to do a `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename ON` statement, and then you have to remember to do a corresponding `SET IDENTITY_INSERT tablename OFF` statement.

---

To achieve a history of the contents of the Map table, I would consider creating a separate "MapHistory" table to store the change history, and use a trigger to maintain it.

```
CREATE TABLE MapHistory (
[change_date] datetime NOT NULL,
[Id]          int      NOT NULL,
[CreatedAt]   datetime NOT NULL,
...
```

To store the "history" of what the row in `Map` looked like BEFORE the update, you can reference the special logical `deleted` table in the trigger.  (For completeness, I might also store a row in the history table when a row is deleted from the Map table.)

```
CREATE TRIGGER map_update ON Map AFTER UPDATE,DELETE AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON
   -- store column values as they existed prior to the update or delete
   INSERT MapHistory (change_date, Id, CreatedAt, ... )
   SELECT CURRDATE(), Id, CreatedAt, ... FROM deleted
END
```

With this approach, your code can be much simpler. All you need to do is perform the `UPDATE` on the `Map` table, and the database will take care of maintaining the MapHistory table.

One slight disadvantage of this approach is that now the "current" values are in one table, and the history of previous values are in another table.

If you would rather have the current values also stored in the `MapHistory` table, you can modify the trigger to fire `AFTER INSERT, UPDATE` instead, and reference the special logical `inserted` table instead, so that you are creating a "replica" of the inserted updated row into the history table.

It's also possible to store both the "old" and the "new" rows in the history table, but then you would really be storing redundant data. In that case, you'd probably want to include a column that indicates whether the row is from the 'Deleted' table or the 'Inserted' table.

```
CREATE TRIGGER map_update ON Map AFTER INSERT,UPDATE,DELETE AS
BEGIN
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   -- store column values as they existed prior to an update or delete
   INSERT MapHistory (source, change_date, Id, CreatedAt, ... )
   SELECT 'D', CURRDATE(), Id, CreatedAt, ... FROM deleted

   -- store column values as they exist after an update or insert
   INSERT MapHistory (source, change_date, Id, CreatedAt, ... )
   SELECT 'I' CURRDATE(), Id, CreatedAt, ... FROM inserted

END
```

---

ADDENDUM:

This approach allows you to have `Id` IDENTITY as a simple primary key in the `Map` table. I think the `change_date` column I added on the `MapHistory` table may be redundant, it may serve the purpose you intended for the `CreatedAt` column.

Comment: The syntax is "SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON;Insert Into ... ;SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName Off. Sorry I made a mistake. The PK for Map are 2 fields: Id and CreatedAt.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend **create another table History** where you keep all the last values including the actual, so you can have your table Map just with the key. 
    `[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL`
You can do this with a trigger or with a procedure, insert the current record in the history table with the alter datetime and in the normal Map table you **update** the record.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative when you want to keep the old parent child relationships is to insert the old data into the new row and then update the old row to the new data. It may take three steps if you have unique indexes or other constraints that would affects there being two record alike except for the surrogate key for the duration of the transaction.

Comment: Can you explain that more please